# "Unable to parser number" while using ethjsonrpc library to connect to geth local ethereum network

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, python

I am getting the error "Unable to parser number" while using [ethjsonrpc library](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ethjsonrpc) to connect to geth local ethereum network. Any help on this will be highly appreciated

```
tx =rpc_.call_with_transaction(rpc_.eth_coinbase(), contract_address, 'Add_Event(string,string,s
tring)', [df.loc[index_value]['UUID'], event_str, column_str])
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\ethjsonrpc\client.py", line 120, in call_with_transaction
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\ethjsonrpc\client.py", line 333, in eth_sendTransaction
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\ethjsonrpc\client.py", line 55, in _call
ethjsonrpc.exceptions.BadResponseError: {u'jsonrpc': u'2.0', u'id': 0, u'error': {u'message': u'Unable to parse number', u'code': -32602}}
```

Comment: Which requests work and which ones don't?

Comment: Why is nobody answering this??

Comment: There's been no response to the comment asking for further information...

Answer (score 2):

I rand into the same problem...
After poking around some I found a pull request that has been waiting in the repo.

Take a look at: https://github.com/ConsenSys/ethjsonrpc/pull/13/commits/f586a4b38784971cea5c62ddf398db48c65de5b0

I had luck with that. Also worth pointing out that if the "address" param is not a string you will get a similar error.

Good luck